# I am using openApi 1.6.15 with springboot but I am getting example value as null for all APIS

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui, swagger-3.0

I am using openApi 1.6.15 with springboot But I am getting example value as null for all APIS

I should get values which are passing in request body.

Current behavior:

[image: Current Behavior]

Expected behavior:

[image: Expected Behavior:]

Comment: 'String' is not null